# run java server from maven

Tags: maven

I need to run a server(implemented in a Java class) from Maven but if I use the exec:java goal, it will block maven and it will not pass to next phases which connect to the server.

Is there any way to run the exec:java task asynchronously, without interrupting the maven execution?

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else looking for recent solutions, try https://github.com/bazaarvoice/maven-process-plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use exec-maven-plugin to run shell script which would start your process and detach from it (letting process to run in background). Something like this:

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <executions> 
      <execution> 
        <id>start-server</id> 
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> 
        <goals> 
          <goal>exec</goal> 
        </goals> 
        <configuration> 
          <executable>src/test/scripts/run.sh</executable> 
          <arguments> 
            <argument>{server.home}/bin/server</argument> 
          </arguments> 
        </configuration> 
      </execution> 
    </executions> 
  </plugin>
```

Where run.sh could be like this (for U*nix platform):

```
#! /bin/sh
$* > /dev/null 2>&1 &
exit 0
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do this with the antrun plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <java fork="true" spawn="true" classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath" className="fully.qualified.package.App"/>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this server class in order to run further integration testing steps in your Maven POM, then it's actually better to consider using a Continuous Integration tool such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), it has a lot of [Plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins/) that allows you to run your own classes, start and stop servers, deploy applications, and many other possibilities, and it's free.